# How to go back to the previous form with no loss of data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a first form where the user designs a hotel for himself/herself. After clicking on a created room from the created floor, the user introduces information to a second form which opens from the first form in order to reserve that room. When a button is clicked on the second form the form should disappear sending the data to the first form then save it to a file in the first form.

My issue is that when I am trying to hide or to close the second form, it either exits the application or it just hides the tab.

Could anyone tell me how to close the second form an get back to the first form without losing any data, any buttons, any text or any information example in a combo box.

Code wise that is what I have in the Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Form1 myStart = new Form1();

            if (myStart.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

And that is what I tried to put in the button that closes the second form, but it does not work :

```
Form2Reservations f2 = new Form2Reservations();
            f2.Close();
```

and I also tried :

```
var main = new Form1();
           main.Show();
           main.BringToFront(); , but it gives me a new Form1 and I do not want to lose everything that I already had in Form1.
```

and I also tried `this.Close();` and `this.Hide();` , but the first one closes the whole application and the second one just puts both tabs on the toolbar.

Also, I am a beginner in C#, I have not taken any University level courses, I am just self-teaching myself with the help of the internet and tutorials.

Thank you.

SECOND EDIT:
When I open up my second form I use this code in form 1:

```
Form2Reservations f2 = new Form2Reservations();
                f2.receiveDataFromForm1(typeOfRoom, numberOfTheRoom, floor);
                f2.ShowDialog();
                this.Hide();
```

The edited changeRoom_Click looks like this :

```
private void changeRoomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
```

And the Program.cs code with static void Main() still looks the same.

My idea is the following : Is there any chance that I am not opening the second form correctly, so when I want to close the second form, it closes both of them, because somehow they are closely connected and `this.Close()` is referring to both forms ? Is that possible ? Would my mistake be in the first form when I call the opening of the second form ?

Comment: Why are you creating a new Form2Reservations in the button to close the form? That is where you should be using this.Close(). Assuming the button to close the second form is a part of the second form, and not the main one. You shouldn't be creating a new form if you want to use the data from the old one. You just need to close the second form, and if you never closed the "main" one it should still be open.

Comment: @Savanna probably it was not a good way to try to close it, but I already tried this.Close() and it closes both of my forms, not just the second one

Comment: Where are you putting the button/the code for the button to close? In Form1 or in Form2Reservations? If it's in form1 it will close the whole thing, if it's in form2reservations it should only close that window. It's a question of what "this" is referring to when you use it.

Comment: @Savanna my first form does not close when I open up the second one, but when I use this.Close(), it closes both forms, not just the second one, as I wanted

Comment: Yes. I know. Where are you calling this.Close()?

Comment: this.Close() is in a button from the second forms, so logically it should close only the second forms

Comment: Post your button click method with this.Close() in it

Comment: I made the edit with posting the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if the DialogResult is set on 'OK'. But you aren't setting the DialogResult before Closing the form, which is why it will return False on the If statement and exits the application.

You need to add
`this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;`
before closing the Form in `changeRoomButton_Click`.

--EDIT:

Lets give it another try.

You are calling `receiveDataFromForm1` before you actually have showed the form, therefor it probably isn't going to return anything. Also, you don't need the hide the existing form when calling `ShowDialog` as it will stay on top until you close it.

Your code is a real mess so I'll just throw something together as an example to help you progress;

In `Program.cs`:

```
        frmReservations reservations = new frmReservations();
        if (reservations.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string result = reservations.yourDesiredResult;
            Application.Run(new frmMain(result));
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Now, inside `frmReservations`:

```
public partial class frmReservations : Form
{
    public string yourDesiredResult = string.Empty;
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        this.yourDesiredResult = "I've been set!";
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now inside `frmMain` you will have to receive that value again we've received from `frmReservations` and set in `Program.cs`:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
      public frmMain(string resultFromReservations)
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           //resultFromReservations holds the string: I've been set
      }
}
```

This is just an example to show you one of the many ways to do this, you will now have to implement it inside your program.

Comment: @ The Dutch Man I just tried it out and still does not work. Although I may have a clue where the problem would be. I will edit my question and put in a code of how I open up the second form.

Comment: I've improved my answer in order to help you out.

Comment: I found a way to fixed it, but I will check out your answer too.

Comment: Probably your answer is better because I just had to delete Application.Exit(); I order to make it work

Comment: I have to say that your code was very hard to read. The best thing is to implement mine, but as long as your code works its your call.

Comment: I have to try to implement yours. My is not professional at all and I am a beginner. But thanks a lot for all your help @The Dutch Man

Comment: Thank you. It is better than my solution. I implemented it correctly and it works. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug. It was in Program.cs :
I had :

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Form1 myStart = new Form1();
            Form2Reservations myLogin = new Form2Reservations();

            if (myStart.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(myLogin);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit(); // here was the mistake
            }
        }
```

All I had to do is to change `Application.Exit();` to  `Application.Run(myStart);`
, but I also needed to include this line in my second form button that closes the second form :

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
```

Thank you guys for help. I could not have fixed it without your help.